# How is the conversion from one class to another possible?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm learning BST in data structures. I encountered some code in my textbook that I can't understand.

I've simplified it this way:

`Tree` should be the binary search Tree.

`Node` is a nested struct in Tree.

`Element` is used to store data in the Node.(All of them originally should be template class and 
 node originally should also store key, etc. However in this case I omit these details.)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Element {

};

class Tree {
   public:
    struct Node {
        Element *element;
    };

    Node *root;
    Element* find() {
        Node *tmp = root;
        return (Element *) tmp; // this line
    }
};

int main() {
    Tree t;
    std::cout << t.find() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In line 16(as commented), what's the function of (Element *) ?
I suppose it's a conversion, but how is the conversion between two different classes possible? (if my assumption is right)

Comment: There is no conversion. `(Element *) tmp;` simply treats a `Node*` as if it was a `Element*`. I dont now if you can safely assume that the address of the first member is the same as the adress of the object, and even if this is the case, proper conversions should be prefered over c-style casts

Comment: The shown code is wrong. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming that `root` is not null, why not return `root->element`?    If `root` is null, then return a null pointer.   Either way, no need for a conversion of  a `Node *` to an `Element *`.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In line 16(as commented), what's the function of (Element *) ?
>
> I suppose it's a conversion

That's right. It's an explicit conversion; also called C-style cast.

> but how is the conversion between two different classes possible?

Conversion between two classes is possible in two cases: One class has a converting constructor, or the other has a conversion operator.

`Node` and `Element` have neither converting constructors nor conversion operators, so they are not convertible to each other. However, the shown program doesn't convert between classes. It converts between **pointers** to classes.

C-style cast performs one or a combination of static cast, const cast and reinterpret cast depending on what the source and target types are. For pointers to unrelated classes, there is no valid static cast, so reinterpret cast is performed.

Reinterpreting a pointer to an unrelated type results in a pointer that has only limited uses. You can compare its equality to another pointer or convert it back to the correct type, but indirecting such reinterpreted pointer has undefined behaviour except in few cases. This is not one of the exceptional cases, so we can conclude that the "function" of the cast is to make the result mostly useless.

---

P.S. There is another problem. `t.root` was never initialised, so it has indeterminate value, and so `Node *tmp = root` reads an indeterminate value, and so the behaviour of the program is undefined.